# Swift: how to express the type like instance [["region":"Region1","states":[["state":"State1","cities":["City1","City2"]]]]]

Tags: swift

Here is an instance:

```
var example1 = [
    [
        "region": "Region1",
        "states": [
            [
                "state": "State1",
                "cities": ["City1", "City2"]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

how to express the type, let me give an simple example, for instance `["apple", "orange", "banana"]`, then the type is `[String]`, now I want to get the type of example1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a `[[String: Any]]`. Is that all you want?

Comment: I want to define a type in code, so compile time. Because I have a plist in that type, I must first define a type, to receive info in that plist file.

Comment: only that simple?

Comment: Given your comment, I'm pretty sure this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It seems like you are reading data from a plist? Why not use `Codable` structs and `PropertyListDecoder` rather than weakly typed dictionaries?

Comment: the reason is pretty simple, I am new student... Everything is on the road to learning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal you showed represents an array of dictionaries. But the dictionaries have different types of values, so the best that Swift can do is to make the value of type `Any`, hence the type of the literal is `[[String: Any]]`. However, to access the dictionary values as something useful, you'd need to do a lot of casting.

This shows that you shouldn't be using dictionaries to store the data. You should write your own structs/classes.

You also said:

> Because I have a plist in that type, I must first define a type, to receive info in that plist file.

You can make those structs/classes `Codable`, and then you can use a `PropertyListDecoder` to read data from the property list:

```
struct Example: Codable {
    let region: String
    let states: [State]

    struct State: Codable  {
        let state: String
        let cities: [String]
    }
}
```

And to decode your property list:

```
let propertyListData: Data = ... // get the data from your property list
let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
do {
    let decoded = decoder.decode([Example].self, from: propertyListData)
    // access your data here via "decoded"
} catch {
    print(error) // error has occurred
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you another question about uploading user's region info to database. If I want the APP can fit to different language using Localization system, I can translate the Plist file using localization. Then a user use different language which can show the languages'  region info. But if uploading to database, what kind of info can be uploaded? directly uploading the region string? maybe is it not ok. uploading the index of the region from an array?(Maybe this method is ok, but developer cannot change the plist file's region order afterward, right)? Do you have any solution

Answer (score 2):

You should make a nested type like:

```
struct Example {
    let region: String
    let states: [State]

    struct State {
        let state: String
        let cities: [String]
    }
}
```

so the result would be like:

```
let examples: [Example] = ...
```

---

## Not recommended

Otherwise, you can make it `[[String: Any]]`, but you will loose all nested types and you need to manually cast all of them.

```
var example1: [[String: Any]] = ...
```